# What's the `DataFrameGroupBy`-equivalent of `dict.keys`?

Tags: pandas

Let me say right-off-the-bat that what I'm looking for is *definitely* not the already-defined `DataFrameGroupBy.keys` attribute.  This attribute holds something *different* from what I'm after.

The rationale for this post's title is that when iterating over a `pandas` `DataFrameGroupBy` object, at each iteration the iterator produces a *pair* that is strongly reminiscent of the key-value pairs generated when iterating over `dict.items()`.  What I want are the "keys", so-to-speak, in these pseudo-key-value pairs; hence, I'm looking for the `DataFrameGroupBy`-equivalent of `dict.keys` (which, again, is ***not*** `DataFrameGroupBy.keys`).

For `dict`'s, one could get the keys with something tortured and convoluted like this

```
keys = [k for k, _ in d.items()]
```

...but, of course, this is unnecessary because `dict` already exposes this information through its `keys` method.  Hence `keys = d.keys()` is all one needs.

Likewise, I could get at the keys I want by doing something tortured and convoluted like

```
keys = [k for k, _ in g]  # for some DataFrameGroupBy object g
```

...but I'm hoping that `DataFrameGroupBy` makes these acrobatics unnecessary, just as `dict` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find `[k for k, _ in g]` "tortured and convoluted" then I'm not sure we share the same standards.. in any event, I think the information you're after can be found in several places.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,1,0.8], "B": [1,2,3,9], "C": [0,1,2,3]})
>>> df
     A  B  C
0  1.0  1  0
1  2.0  2  1
2  1.0  3  2
3  0.8  9  3
>>> g = df.groupby("A")
>>> [k for k, _ in g]
[0.8, 1.0, 2.0]
>>> g.groups
{1.0: [0, 2], 2.0: [1], 0.80000000000000004: [3]}
>>> g.groups.keys()
[1.0, 2.0, 0.80000000000000004]
>>> set(g.groups)
set([1.0, 2.0, 0.80000000000000004])
```

And `g.indices` too, I think.  If you care about the order, you can use `result_index`:

```
>>> g.grouper.result_index
Index([0.8, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=object)
```

Comment: As I took pains to explain, `[k for k, _ in g]` is "tortured and convoluted" to the same degree that `[k for k, _ in d.items()]` is a tortured and convoluted way of getting at `d.keys()`.

Comment: @kjo: oh, I understood you.  I simply don't agree that it's either tortured or convoluted.

Comment: &#64;DSM : if you don't think that `[k for k, _ in d.items()]` is a tortured and convoluted way of accessing `d.keys()`, then, I agree with you, we have different standards.

Comment: I don't think this discussion is likely to be productive.  Incidentally, I only found out about the above methods by typing `g.` at an IPython console and looking at the objects that were contained inside: it's a handy approach for finding out what's available.

Comment: &#64;DSM: thanks for the tip, but it doesn't work for me.  If I type `g.` (`g` followed by `.`), nothing happens; and if I then hit `[Enter]`, I get a `SyntaxError`...  I'm running iPython within a text-only shell.  Maybe this explains the difference...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have been more specific: `g.` and then hit TAB.  This should work with most objects.